# How to get this date time format from UNIX time stamp?

Tags: php, datetime

I need to convert the UNIX time stamp to this format in PHP **2013-07-31T09:06:02-0400**
I have used the below code to create UNIX timestamp to get the next day UNIX time stamp from the current.

```
$localtime = time();

$hour = gmdate("H",$localtime);
$minute = gmdate("i",$localtime);
$second = gmdate("s",$localtime);
$month = gmdate("n",$localtime);
$day = gmdate("j",$localtime); $day = $day + $timestamp;
$year = gmdate("Y",$localtime);
$createtimestamp =  gmmktime ($hour, $minute,$second,$month,$day,$year);
```

Thanks.

Comment: And what happends..?Is there any error..?And whats is the value of $timestamp.?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, `date()` format supports 'c', which is ISO 8601 format.

```
    c   ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)  2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00
```

Your code can be simplified like this:

```
date('c'); // using current UNIX timestamp by omitting second parameter
```

EDIT

---

What you want to get is 'ISO 8601' formatted **string**, not a **timestamp** which is an **int**. Generating 'ISO 8601' date string is simply done by calling `date('c')`.

Also, you can manipulate the your **timestamp** variable to offset days/hours, and then feed the variable to the second parameter of `date()` call.

```
$timestamp = time();
$timestamp_with_offset = $timestamp + 3600; // an hour later
date('c', $timestamp_with_offset);
```

Comment: Hi i have converted the unix to format $createtimestamp =  date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s',$createtimestamp) ; but dont know how to get the rest -400 portion

Comment: @anu I've edited my answer. Try `date('c', $createtimestamp)` - but make sure `$createtimestamp` is an ___int___, not a ___string___.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is redundant, you can do what you want using [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) with very little code:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Athens'));
echo $date->format(DATE_ISO8601);
```

I don't know what your timezone is, I just set one at random to illustrate my answer.

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/WlXIp)